# The resource path [cxf-ehcache.xml] is not valid

Tags: tomcat, cxf, wss4j

I'm trying to implement message-level encryption. Specifically, the body of the SOAP message will be encrypted.
I'm trying encrypt the traffic from the client to the web service.

The client sends the encrypted data successfully:

```
UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=[""]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="EK-2F22184B9EAAC6244514331031642721">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=testkey</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>1940918168</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue>n6hH/RHguV2YCqZxI2Sq+X6hnaDm/OSUJsNRvcsxEHZw6lpdR+JitcbEfdv2huhsQ0HbtGjj0dfOa9pOCiwuaZW5wdR2Nq8kq85lZ4g2l/rHkGBRch19/P2oT0wXHIh/qQRHSqDhBg4bUrLKlzw+mA/H8SZimFvUz5xymwzKaQcv8puc0r9yKukQRmKVCjiS7enBznN0PdAfoitKdJYIm44/UaXa+CLwySPAw1cHpETAWoKclMqtL8Wgs9cN8+aYCmbC8kSDS+DURXMWc8ilVcirrYVrPAyEVZIX/NE9Pe8SIQmfgD5GHdFaIOPYcmf0i1w4/YQdTxzCFIXlwNkI0w==</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
          <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-2F22184B9EAAC6244514331031642892"/>
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
      </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-2F22184B9EAAC6244514331031642892" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
          <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-2F22184B9EAAC6244514331031642721"/>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:CipherValue>PNHM0fKuMOHtpm0rGSpR0siGeiFRz/4Dwgwauwe2C6usChfH5a7PDXimplOvYSKE9d8zTNXie3tDMfprHLS/hPD0vABlSGA4haGMYrelFKNgAU8BhXbBfrQimD7e8ue6gV/BBwAGa0rgoExPYJQh0w==</xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

But the web service response is bad:
NFORMACIÓN: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {connection=[close], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Date=[Sun, 31 May 2015 20:12:44 GMT], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], transfer-encoding=[chunked]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>The resource path [cxf-ehcache.xml] is not valid</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The resource path [cxf-ehcache.xml] is not valid
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.factorial(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathutility.test.TestMathUtility.main(TestMathUtility.java:57)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The resource path [cxf-ehcache.xml] is not valid
```

I am using:
Apache Tomcat 8 and Apache CXF 2.6.13

Comment: Some more info required, is there any file cxf-ehcache.xml in your project?

Comment: maybe this can help you.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201410.mbox/%3CCAB8XdGAt8a=6N2cZ7Zh17Wiq9oYE7JML=JXV5Qqc_zsYoFN6tw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that tomcat8 does not like resources that not start with /. So you need to prefix the default resource (cxf-ehcache.xml) with "/". The answer is given in [CXF mail archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201410.mbox/%3CCAB8XdGAt8a=6N2cZ7Zh17Wiq9oYE7JML=JXV5Qqc_zsYoFN6tw@mail.gmail.com%3E).

What you need to do is to set the property ws-security.cache.config.file, in order to replace the default value (cxf-ehcache.xml) with "/cxf-ehcache.xml", as explained in [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html).

You can do this by adding the property under your endpoint bean declaration, within your CXF XML configuration :

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="your id"
   ...    
   <jaxws:properties>
   ... 
    <entry key="ws-security.cache.config.file"  value="/cxf-ehcache.xml"/>
   </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```